# Best tool to trace php file

Tags: php

Im new to php and i want to find out in what file actually contains the rendered HTML that i see. Seems like the header parts of the page are in the includes folder. Took me 2 days to find this out. Is there an easier way or tool to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all depends on the type of PHP application you are using. Many people separate HTML code from the PHP code, and right so!

However, if you are working with code that has HTML and PHP mingled together and it's not specifically designated to a folder such as "`Templates`" or "`Views`" then your PHP life will begin a little bit tricky!

To solve your dilemma, here is a suggestion:

**Suggestion 1:**

- I would grab a copy of [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) (Just the PHP one is ok).
- Create a new project with the files
- With the new project listed on the side,
- Select the "Sources Icon" Press `CTRL+F` Search for various `<html>` tags, and itll show up in the search result list.

**Suggestion 2:**

- Grab a copy of Notepad++ (If you are on Windows)
- Select all your PHP Files (Hopefully its under 100)
- Drag them into [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and let them open
- Press `CTRL+F`, then move to the "Find in Files"
- Type in some `<html>` tags you are looking for, and you'll get a list at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's generally about the easiest you'll find. "What file actually contains the rendered HTML that I see" depends on the setup you're using. A CMS might have the various HTML parts coming from dozens or hundreds of files. A small custom site might have everything in one file.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a temporary logging function where every time you render parts of a page, you write something in your logs.

You can do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
createPage(){
  render(head); //with log
  render(body); //with log
  render(footer); //with log
}
```

But it all depends on the setup you are using as mentioned by ceejayoz.